# how to solve Can't connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1' (10061)”?

Tags: connection, mysql-workbench

I am getting this error,

[image]

[image]

I have tried,

1.C:\cd Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.X\BIN

Output : 
C:\Users\administrator>C:\cd Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.X\BIN
'C:\cd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

2.searched "MySQL56" from "services.msc" but there is no service as MySQL56

how do fix this?

Answer (score 2):

> 2.searched "MySQL56" from "services.msc" but there is no service as MySQL56

Clearly, you have no server installed on your box. Download the MySQL Windows Installer to get all the parts you need in one package.